# Neo4J start windows runs only one time in windows10 - why?

Tags: windows, neo4j

I just installed Neo4J community for windows10 . The menu can launch Neo4J and shows the small window with 'choose database' and 'stop' and 'start'.
Everything seems ok, i can start, use the db, and stop.
I can restart or stop, as long i don't close this small window.
If i do, **i can no more start Neo4J** as it is still running in background (seen in task manager ) and never show again this small window.
As a workaround, i kill the app in task manager, then the window re appears on next start .
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the window has gone away, the process itself is still running (neo4j-ce.exe). If you open the task manager, look under "Background Processes" and find it there. Select it and then press "End task". You can restart Neo4J after that. I haven't found an answer as to why you have to do this, but it seems to have popped up with the 3.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

When the Neo4j database is stopped by clicking the stop button and the GUI closed by clicking the X in the corner, the Neo4j process continues to run in the background as described by chrisvest [Neo4j process still in memory after stopping and closing the window](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8504). This is a feature. However, trying to launch the GUI again from the exe or a link to the exe will not work. You will have to locate the small Neo4j icon in the taskbar and click on it. The GUI will reappear. There is no need to kill the Neo4j.ce thread or restart the computer.